# Why can't I install a NuGet package which has target framework profile of 136?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, nuget

I am trying to install [Humanizer](http://humanizr.net/) (see also [GitHub](https://github.com/MehdiK/Humanizer) and [NuGet Gallery](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Humanizer) pages) using the NuGet package manager inside **Visual Studio 2010**.  The documentation suggests it should support .NET 4+.

Issuing the following command on a brand new empty MVC4 project:

> PM> install-package Humanizer

Gives me the following result:

> Successfully installed 'Humanizer 1.26.1'.
>   Successfully uninstalled 'Humanizer 1.26.1'.
>   Install failed. Rolling back...
>   Install-Package : Could not install package 'Humanizer 1.26.1'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.0', but the package does not contain any assembly references that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.
>   At line:1 char:16
>   + install-package <<<<  Humanizer
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand
>
> PM>

I contacted the author directly (and subsequently raised [an issue on GitHub](https://github.com/MehdiK/Humanizer/issues/299)).  He mentioned that the package targets Profile136 (can also be [seen in the csproj file](https://github.com/MehdiK/Humanizer/blob/master/src/Humanizer/Humanizer.csproj#L14)) which should support .NET 4:

```
<TargetFrameworkProfile>Profile136</TargetFrameworkProfile>
```

I had a look around and read [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20518424/building-portable-class-library-project-in-build-server-fails) which discusses *building* portable class libraries.  Having read that, I discovered that Visual Studio 2010 [requires an add-in](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/b0e0b5e9-e138-410b-ad10-00cb3caf4981/) to enable building of PCLs.

I realise I'm not building here, but I installed it anyway, along with the [updated reference assemblies v4.6](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40727).

Having looked in the following folder:

*C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETPortable\v4.0\Profile*

I discovered that I only have profiles up to 131, but no 136.

An [answer to the SO question mentioned earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20523850/483162) suggests that 136 was added in the Windows Phone SDK 8.0.  However I can't install this on Windows 7.

**Why can't I install this package in Visual Studio 2010?**  Is it because I don't have profile 136 on my machine, or is that only required for *building* PCLs?

Note that I have installed other NuGet packages successfully, e.g. log4net.

Comment: Strange. You should not need to have the Portable Class Libraries installed to install the Humanizer NuGet package into a project that targets .NET 4.0. The Profile 136 is in the Portable v4.6 reference assemblies - to install it you need to unzip the zip file that the installer installs. However you should not need to have any PCLs installed. To test this I renamed the .NETPortable library and with an empty MVC 4 project could add a reference to Humanizer in VS 2010. Do you have a recent version of NuGet installed?

Comment: Also might be worth looking at the Humanizer NuGet package in the cache on your local machine (C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\NuGet\Cache) and see what it contains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not need to have the Portable Class Libraries installed to add the Humanizer NuGet package to a project that targets .NET 4.0.

The Profile 136 is in the Portable v4.6 reference assemblies. To install this you need to unzip the zip file that the installer installs. However you should not need to have any PCLs installed.

As a test I renamed the .NETPortable library directory so NuGet did not detect the portable libraries. Then with an empty ASP.NET MVC 4 project I could add a reference to Humanizer in Visual Studio 2010.

If you have a recent version of NuGet installed then it should work.

Comment: Thank you so much @MattWard. I upgraded NuGet from 2.0.30717.9005 to 2.8.50313.31 and the package installed correctly.