# How to keep profiles for portable libraries up to date

Tags: c#, .net, dll, profile, portable-class-library

This might be a silly question, but it have been beating me a couple of times. I am part of a larger project where some of the projects are portable. One of my responsibilities are to make sure that the build on Teamcity is going okey.

Last week, the the build failed and it there was one missing assembly. To be correct, [System.Collections.Concurrent.dll](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.concurrent(v=vs.110).aspx) was missing. First thing I did was checking out the project and that was a portable project. Then I checked the project file and found that it used Profile78. When I found the .Net45 folder, I could see the dll in there, but when I look into the Profiles folder and then found Profile78 folder, the dll was missing.

Just copy the dll from the Net45 folder and into Net45\Profiles\Profile78 folder works and the build could complete without errors.

Today one of the developers that took a clean checkout from the repository had the same issue. So I helped him do the same thing. I hardly think that this is the "correct" way of keeping the profiles updated.

I have been searching a bit around and did not really found anyone that had another way of just copy the files. Is this really the way to do it? Or is it some other and better ways of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

After I asked this question, I found by the help of the releated section on SO, [SO: Building Portable Class Library Project in build server fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20518424/building-portable-class-library-project-in-build-server-fails?rq=1).

This sounds to me to be a much better way of keeping the profiles updated. At least check if there are any updates next time I get a related problem.