# Visual Studio 2013/15 doesn't load portable Silverlight projects after VS2017 install

Tags: c#, visual-studio, silverlight, visual-studio-2017, portable-class-library

After installing Visual Studio 2017 on my workplace, I can't build legacy solutions with a common, portable library anymore. The library was supposed to work both under regular .NET and Silverlight. The .proj file hasn't been changed for a very long time and worked perfectly, until installing VS2017. I think it's not possible with VS2017, but VS2013 and VS2015 also can't load it anymore.

Is it possible that VS2017 installation removed the Silverlight support, even from the old Visual Studios?

**Edit:** I could compile it, after using VS 2015, to remove the targets Windows 8 and Windows Phone Silverlight 8, leaving only .NET Framework 4 and Silverlight 5. VS 2013 could also load it after the change. The project was supposed to only work with Webbrowser Silverlight, not anything Windows 8 or phone, probably targeted by default.

**VS 2015 error:**

There was a mismatch between the processor architecture of the project being built "MSIL" and the processor architecture of the reference "C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\mscorlib.dll", "x86". This mismatch may cause runtime failures. Please consider changing the targeted processor architecture of your project through the Configuration Manager so as to align the processor architectures between your project and references, or take a dependency on references with a processor architecture that matches the targeted processor architecture of your project.

*(note: the project properties under Build have only "AnyCPU", I can't switch to x86 anymore, not even when setting the solution to x86)*

**VS 2013 error:**

VS2013 doesn't load the project at all. Upon clicking "Reload Project" in context menu, I get the message:

"Visual Studio update required

One or more projects require a framework SDK (.NETPortable, Version=v4.0, Profile=Profile136) that is either not installed or is included as part of a future update to Visual Studio"

The download link only takes me to the Microsoft landing page, nothing related.

Answer (score 0):

Installing Visual Studio 2017 doesn't affect Visual Studio 2015's support for Silverlight.

An answer to a similar question can be found here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/21725379/90287

> Try installing [Microsoft .NET Portable Library Reference Assemblies
>   4.6](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40727)